# Can I use a header tag in footer inside section?

Tags: html, html5

I want to know if I can use a header tag in footer inside section.  I also want to know if this follows SEO.

For example, I made four section boxes in footer:

```
<footer>
<div class="ftr_top"><img src="media/footer.png"></div>
<div class="ftr_bottom">
<section class="ftr_section">
<header class="ftr_head">
<h3>Box 1</h3>
</header>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="ftr_section">
<header class="ftr_head">
<h3>Box 2</h3>
</header>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="ftr_section">
<header class="ftr_head">
<h3>Box 3</h3>
</header>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not valid HTML5 to have a `<header>` element inside a `<footer>` element. You could have checked this yourself on this site:

http://validator.w3.org/check

For using `<header>`, `<footer>` and `<section>` correctly, see this page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer

For even more technical details, see the HTML5 specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element

*Special thanks to [@amon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/21609/amon) for the links!*

Comment: It is the general consensus by web developers that the “w3schools” website should not be used as a reference. I recommend you link to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) instead. It's [page on `<footer>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) clearly states that it cannot include a `<header>`. You could also link directly to the [description of `<footer>` in the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element).

Comment: Thanks @amon, I wasn't aware that w3schools is so bad. I updated my post using the better links you gave.